# Problem with NSPopupButtonCell bindings

Tags: cocoa, binding, master-detail, nspopupbuttoncell

I'm trying to achieve something similar to the [Apple Master-Detail pop-up cell example](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CocoaBindings/Tasks/onerelation.html) but the bindings don't seem to be working for me.

My app allows users to build up a stageplay; so I have a table view of `acts`. Each act can have a list of `lines` so the acts table view drives a second table view of lines (so selecting act one updates the lines table view with the lines of that act).

This setup seems to be working fine.

Each line is of course spoken by a character, so my document object has a list of `characters` as well as a list of acts. What I want is a pop-up cell in my lines table with values taken from the `characters` array.

So I followed the steps in that Apple tutorial but it doesn't work...

- If I bind the `content` of the table view column to the `CharactersController.arrangedObjects` and the `selectedObject` to `LinesController.arrangedObjects.character` then the binding works (when I select a value from the pop-up it updates the underlying `line` object with the new character), **but** the list shows `<Character ...>` entries
- If I then bind the column's `contentValues` to `CharactersController.arrangedObjects.name` then I get the following debug error when I run the app:

  ```
  2011-03-16 11:28:49.783 ScriptPreparer[5176:903] Cocoa Bindings: 
  Error setting value <Character: 0x100144f60> of object 
  <NSPopUpButtonCell: 0x100153ff0> through binding selectedObject
  ```
- If I remove the `selectedObject` binding then I still get the `<Character...>` output in the list.

It seems like the `contentValues` binding is the broken one. What am I doing wrong?

Here are my bindings:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered what the problem was - I had bindings set on the `NSTableView` as well as the Table column and the `NSPopupButtonCell` which was causing strange things to happen.

My conclusion is now that **any table bindings not on the table column are WRONG**